# Stock Count Inventory Management in Excel

Tags: excel, inventory, inventory-management

I am developing a dummy feasibility model for the restaurant business. The model I have made so far is attached. I want the model to automatically calculate the inventory stock left so that the flags can be raised for the items to be reordered. This requires the total stock utilized by the recipes cooked so far.

Please check out the [excel file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfxaspxy57rqo54/Model.xlsx?dl=0).

Thanks.

Comment: Asim, what's keeping you from putting a simple formula into the cells? For example in cell `J4` you could write `=(U5*N10)/1000`. Yet, I'd like to suggest to move all inventory **movements** to a separate sheet. Like this you could also easily show the difference between items ordered and items in stock. With your model it might happen that something is ordered but not yet in stock (received) and someone else orders it again.

Comment: Ralph, this is a dummy model with just 2 recipes. Imagine a model with 20 recipes. The formula has to calculate the utilized items by running an iterative vlookup on all the recipes listed in the revenue schedule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There probably is no one formula solution to this problem, since you want to cross reference over 2 data relations (InventoryId-RecipeId, RecipeId-QtySold) and then sum up the results.
It is particularly difficult because you enter all data into a single sheet, in a non-relational form (albeit human-readable).

A simple solution may be introducing a "Qty Sold" column P:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ods6.png

You can get the qty sold with a simple lookup from your monthly revenue section:

```
=VLOOKUP($N$3,$U$1:$V$100,2,FALSE)
```

Building on this intermediate column, enter

```
=SUM(IF($M$1:$M$100=B4,$N$1:$N$100,0)*$P$1:$P$100)/1000
```

into cell J4 and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER (array formula). You can then copy cell J4 to J5:J19.

From the bottom of my heart, I want to strongly urge you not to use Excel for your production setup. You already experienced its limitations building only this basic "model". A real world business should be using a real database connected to a well thought out user interface.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ulli, it worked perfectly. Actually I am not using excel for my production setup. I wanted to build a feasibility model of a restaurant since a long time. Finally giving it a shot. This is just for a feasibility study.

Once again, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome ;) It's just that I have already experienced something similar being used for a business - it was then constantly being extended with more functionality, until finally nobody could use the gigantic tool anymore^^. Just remember, Excel is almost never a permanent solution for a task.